# Site working fine in Preview but when accessing the index.html file, the background images are missing

Tags: html, css

I have encountered an issue and I really don't know what is causing it. I am working in brackets and the site works perfectly in preview.

However, when I click on  the actual index.html file my background images from my scss are missing.

- Uploaded images via src are working
- Rest of my sass is working
- Js is working
- Only the images for my backgrounds ( using url ) are not working anymore, so I presume it has something to do with the url.

An example of the scss:

```
.jumbfirst {
    background: url('/imagini/images/background6.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    width: $fullwidth;
    min-height: 600px;      
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide some code?

Comment: Can you post the code? To see the urls? Maybe no Internet? Or something blocks the connection to the pictures?

Comment: I updated the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your devel setup, meaning you use relative paths but depending on the structure of your files and how you run your index.html the browser reads the paths differently. 
I'm guessing that double clicking the index.html file doesn't show it from your local server but as an absolute path like

**file:///Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/devel/test/index.html**

This example is from a MAC and it's the path to the **index.html** in the file system.

You should either have a local devel server (e.g. [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)) or if you already have one change the address in your browser to something like

**http://localhost/devel/test/index.html**

In this case I'm calling **index.html** from my local server, inside the devel/test/ directory.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's because path relativity to your image file. When it comes to domain image shows because the path is set to current directory. But with index.html image path will be converted to something like this `http://www.example.com/index.html/imagini/images/background6.jpg`. Since the browser try to find image in that path image wont be found. Check your console in developer tools of chrome browser. You may get more details from there.

This might be fixed by removing starting `/` from your image url or creating a .htaccess with proper parameters.

Comment: You are correct regarding the issue. It is a path problem, and it does show in the console log, but the first solution doesn't work and the .htaccess would be a bit of a hustle.  Any alternatives to that ?

Comment: Another alternative method is to use absolute path, such as `http://www.example.com/imagini/images/background6.jpg`. But I would not recommend it as it needs to be change once after any domain name changes. Or you can try to include inline style for `body` tag